# Regex - finding capital words in string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to learn how to use regular expressions but have a question. Let's say I have the string

```
line = 'Cow Apple think Woof`
```

I want to see if `line` has at least two words that begin with capital letters (which, of course, it does). In Python, I tried to do the following

```
import re
test = re.search(r'(\b[A-Z]([a-z])*\b){2,}',line)
print(bool(test))
```

but that prints `False`. If I instead do

```
test = re.search(r'(\b[A-Z]([a-z])*\b)',line)
```

I find that `print(test.group(1))` is `Cow` but `print(test.group(2))` is `w`, the last letter of the first match (there are no other elements in `test.group`).

Any suggestions on pinpointing this issue and/or how to approach the problem better in general?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The last letter of the match is in group because of inner parentheses. Just drop those and you'll be fine.

```
>>> t = re.findall('([A-Z][a-z]+)', line)
>>> t
['Cow', 'Apple', 'Woof']
>>> t = re.findall('([A-Z]([a-z])+)', line)
>>> t
[('Cow', 'w'), ('Apple', 'e'), ('Woof', 'f')]
```

The count of capitalised words is, of course, `len(t)`.

Comment: Thank you as well. Right, I didn't need that parenthesis there at all!

Comment: More, you do not need any parentheses here. `re.findall(r'\b[A-Z][a-z]+\b', line)` is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

I use the `findall` function to find all instances that match the regex. The use `len` to see how many matches there are, in this case, it prints out `3`. You can check if the length is greater than 2 and return a `True` or `False`.

```
import re

line = 'Cow Apple think Woof'

test = re.findall(r'(\b[A-Z]([a-z])*\b)',line)
print(len(test) >= 2)
```

If you want to use only regex, you can search for a capitalized word then some characters in between and another capitalized word.

```
test = re.search(r'(\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b)(.*)(\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b)',line)
print(bool(test))
```

- `(\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b)` - finds a capitalized word
- `(.*)` - matches 0 or more characters
- `(\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b)` - finds the second capitalized word

This method isn't as dynamical since it will not work for trying to match 3 capitalized word.

Comment: @Argon, i added a pure regex solution, not sure if it's better

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

sent = "His email is abc@some.com, however his wife uses xyz@gmail.com"

x = re.findall('[A-Za-z]+@[A-Za-z\.]+', sent)

print(x)
```

If there is a period at the end of an email ID (abc@some,com.), it will be returned at the end of the email address. However, this can be dealt separately.