# How to remove words starting with lowercase from a sentence using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

"I am trying to remove the words starting with lowercase using regular expression but I am not getting the required output."

My input was "apply to this bill and are made a part thereof Illiam B GEISSLER"

```
import re 
text = "apply to this bill and are made a part thereof Illam B GEISSLER"  
result = re.sub(r"\w[a-z]", "", text)  
print(result)
```

I got the output as " I B GEISSLER"
Required output as " Illiam B GEISSLER"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try finding the pattern `\b[a-z]+\s*`, and replace with empty string:

```
text = "apply to this bill and are made a part thereof Illam B GEISSLER"  
result = re.sub(r'\b[a-z]+\s*', "", text).strip()
print(result)
```

This prints:

```
Illam B GEISSLER
```

The idea behind the pattern `\b[a-z]+\s*` is that it matches only entire *words* surrounded on both sides by word boundaries.  Note that we call `strip` to remove any remaining whitespace.

One other subtle point is that the pattern removes all whitespace on the RHS of each matching lowercase letter.  This is to leave the text readable, should, for example, some matching words lie in between some non matching words:

```
text = "United States Of a bunch of states called America"  
result = re.sub(r'\b[a-z]+\s*', "", text).strip()
print(result)
```

This correctly prints:

```
United States Of America
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search the capitalize words
in the link you can find an example

[Regex - finding capital words in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422093/regex-finding-capital-words-in-string)

Answer (score 1):

This expression might also work:

```
\s*\b[a-z][a-z]*
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/kSqt52/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"\s*\b[a-z][a-z]*"

test_str = "apply to this bill and are made a part thereof Illam B GEISSLER apply to this bill and are made a part thereof Illam B GEISSLER"

subst = ""

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

or maybe this one:

```
([A-Z].*?\b\s*)
```

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"([A-Z].*?\b\s*)"
test_str = "apply to this bill and are made a part thereof Illam B GEISSLER apply to this bill and are made a part thereof Illam B GEISSLER"
print("".join(re.findall(regex, test_str)))
```

#### Output

```
Illam B GEISSLER Illam B GEISSLER
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/RNwZFr/1/)

Comment: The `\b` in `\s*\b` is redundant, because the interface between a whitespace and letter is by definition a word boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
import re
text = "apply to this bill and are made a part thereof Illam B GEISSLER"
result = re.sub(r"(\b[a-z]+)", '', text).strip()
print(result)
```

Output

```
Illam B GEISSLER
```